# É possível ligar minha aplicação feita em Laravel com o Vue ou Angular?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, angular

Iniciei um projeto que futuramente terá um aplicativo em **Vue** ou **Angular**.

Minha dúvida é saber se é possível fazer esta ligação entre o sistema e o aplicativo e se essa "ligação" pode ser feita através de uma **API** ou por outra funcionalidade.

Answer (score 0):

O Laravel já vem pre-configurado com Vue JS. Você pode trabalhar o Laravel em forma de api e o front separado sem nenhum problema, tanto Vue JS quanto Angular etc...

Vai de gosto.

Saudações,